# Creating data with DX/CLI referencing existing records

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

When setting up a scratch org for CI/QA or development purposes certain "records" like the standard profiles and some other record like Accounts & Contacts ("hasSampleData": "true") are created during scratch org creation.

When importing additional records (custom objects) that reference each other sfdx force:data:tree:export & ...:import allow cross-references in between those imported records. Is there a possibility to reference existing records like profiles, users, accounts or contacts in those to-be-imported records as well?

I see options to do that with a script and create everything step-by-step, always searching for the record based on attributes like the name and using the record id for the record-to-be-imported but that seems very cumbersome to me.